# Improper SQL Statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Table 1 `Questions`

```
ID | Name | Category
1 | xyz  | 1
2 | abc  | 1
3 | ghj  | 2
4 | tyu  | 3
```

Table 2 `Data`

```
ID | QuestionID | Category
1 | 2    | 1
2 | 3    | 2
```

I want results to be all of the questions from `Question` table. WHERE Category = 1

```
ID | Question | DataID
1  | xyz   | NO
2  | abc   | YES (data id=1 ie questionid= 2)
3  | ghj   | NO (data id=2 ie questionid= 3 but where category = 2 fail so 'NO')
4  | tyu   | NO
```

So i need to display YES if data present else NO.

Comment: and what have you tried to achieve

Comment: So... you have a Question table and a pivot table... where does `DataID` come from?

Comment: **Sql <> MySql** which one is it and ***what have you tried***, we are not a code service... Also remove the `php` tag as it's clearly not involved...

Comment: Please share what have you tried so far or your thought process about approaching the problem.

Comment: DataID is from `Data` table (ID) and questionID are stored.

Comment: Use an `outer join`...

Comment: What about display Yes or no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `LEFT JOIN` along with `CASE WHEN` Statement.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT
Q.ID,
Q.Name AS 'Question',
CASE WHEN D.QuestionID IS NULL THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END AS DataID
FROM Questions Q LEFT JOIN Data D
ON Q.ID = D.QuestionID
ORDER BY Q.ID;
```

[**MySQL JOINS**](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/)

[**Demo Here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b8eed/1/0)

**EDIT:**

For your edited requirement

> I want results to be all of the questions from Question table. WHERE
>   Category = 1

**Query:**

```
SELECT
Q.ID,
Q.Name AS 'Question',
CASE WHEN D.QuestionID IS NULL OR D.category <> 1 THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END AS DataID
FROM Questions Q LEFT JOIN Data D
ON Q.ID = D.QuestionID
ORDER BY Q.ID;
```

[**Updated Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/304e60/3/0)

Comment: I didn't use `LIMIT`. Wait couple of minutes. I am sharing the SQL FIDDLE of it.

Comment: Please check the **SQL FIDDLE**. @MohammedKumel

Comment: thas cool.. If table `data` contained another column as category SO if i need to display particular category using WHERE Category = 1 how its added?  - @1000111

Comment: Look at this [**fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/304e60/1/0). I've added `category` column in `Data` table and changed the query to get data having `category = 1`. @MohammedKumel

Comment: well i need other questions to be displayed as well and written NO if DataID not found

Comment: better show me sample output. I didn't understand what you are actually looking for.

Comment: Its in the question.

` ID | Question | DataID
    1  | xyz   | NO
    2  | abc   | YES (data id=1 ie questionid= 2)
    3  | ghj   | YES (data id=2 ie questionid= 3)
    4  | tyu   | NO `

Comment: What you showed in 1st is correct.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b8eed/1/0 There all questions are shown. If where clause is true then Yes ELSE NO

Comment: Question updated. See output. Category must match & display all rows from Questions table.

Comment: What you have given is completely perfect. I have long list of `Data` .

Seems like Category from `Data` aint filtered so all questions linked with Data are displaying irrespective  of where category <> 1

Comment: Note that COALESCE conforms to the SQL standard